# How can I determine which checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<table>
<tbody>
              <tr>  
                <th>Select</th>
                    <th>User Id</th>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Is Banned?</th>
                    <th>registration_date</th>
                
                </tr>
                {data.map((item, i) => (
                    <tr key={i}>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" checked={isChecked} /></td>
                        <td>{item.user_id}</td>
                        <td>{item.user_name}</td>
                        <td className="isbanned">{item.isbanned}</td>
                        <td>{item.registration_date}</td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody></table>
```

[image]

this is my code as you see in up. My question is:

How can I detect user_id 1 checbox is checked?

How should I change my code? or what I can use for that?

Comment: Give your input a data attribute to define it in your `onChange` handler.

Comment: className={i} with that it can get class. so every checkbox will have different classes. I will look now for onChange is able to detect class

Comment: That's not classes are meant for. That's what data attributes are meant for.

Comment: could you show to me as an example code

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const data = [
  {
    user_id: "some-id",
    user_name: "Me",
    isbanned: "no",
    registration_date: "2000",
  },
]

function StackOverflow() {
  const [selectedUserIds, setSelectedUserIds] = useState([])

  const addOrRemoveId = (id) => {
    setSelectedUserIds((state) => {
      if (state.includes(id)) {
        // If new id exists in current list then we remove it from state
        return selectedUserIds.filter((currentId) => currentId !== id)
      }
      // Else we add the item id to our state
      return [...state, id]
    })
  }
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Select</th>
          <th>User Id</th>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Is Banned?</th>
          <th>registration_date</th>
        </tr>
        {data.map(({ user_id, ...item }) => (
          <tr key={user_id}>
            <td>
              <input
                checked={selectedUserIds.includes(user_id)}
                onChange={() => addOrRemoveId(user_id)}
                type="checkbox"
              />
            </td>
            <td>{user_id}</td>
            <td>{item.user_name}</td>
            <td className="isbanned">{item.isbanned}</td>
            <td>{item.registration_date}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
```

**To consider:** Never use an index or a combination string of them as component keys. Keys are intended to be unique, if you have an userId already, then use it as that key id